# Pricing table MySQL table design I need the database design for the the plans

Tags: mysql, database-design

Please find the attached image for detail pricing plan for this plans. I want to create MySQL table to store the prices.

[image: Pricing plans image]

Comment: When you say you need a database design, if you are the software engineer on this project, is this not your job? What are you stuck on in particular?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. To better help you, could you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: i want to create mysql tables for store prices

Comment: i have no idea how to start

Comment: have you read the manual about the "create table" statement?

Comment: i know the create table but don't know how to structure the table, thats what i tried to say, i use Larval commands to create tables

Comment: @MahmudNaseem Please read [how do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you can show your effort, that will be help to show you the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/a-data-model-for-a-leasing-office. Is that something you'd be able to do for your problem? And this might help you realizing it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbm-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave pgmodeler a try, and that tool generated the following SQL (the syntax is PostgreSQL 10, but it should give you an idea):

```
-- object: public.hires | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.hires CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.hires(
        id smallint NOT NULL,
        name varchar,
        CONSTRAINT hires_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
ALTER TABLE public.hires OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO public.hires (id, name) VALUES (E'1', E'8 hours');
INSERT INTO public.hires (id, name) VALUES (E'2', E'whole day');
INSERT INTO public.hires (id, name) VALUES (E'3', E'6 hours (suites)');

-- object: public.rooms | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.rooms CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.rooms(
        id smallint NOT NULL,
        type char(1),
        name varchar,
        addhr_price money,
        corkage_price money,
        CONSTRAINT ballrooms_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
COMMENT ON COLUMN public.rooms.type IS 'Ballroom or Suite';
ALTER TABLE public.rooms OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'1', E'B', E'Whole venue', E'1500', E'1000');
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'2', E'B', E'Grand Ballroom Exclusive', E'1000', E'750');
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'3', E'B', E'Grand Ballroom Non-Exclusive', E'1000', E'750');
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'4', E'B', E'Meridian Ballroom Exclusive', E'750', E'500');
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'5', E'B', E'Meridian Ballroom Non-Exclusive', E'750', E'500');
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'6', E'S', E'Eternity & Infinity', E'350', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'7', E'S', E'Eternity & Infinity  (MG catering)', E'350', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'8', E'S', E'Eternity', E'250', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'9', E'S', E'Eternity (MG catering)', E'250', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'10', E'S', E'Infinity', E'150', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO public.rooms (id, type, name, addhr_price, corkage_price) VALUES (E'11', E'S', E'Infinity (MG catering)', E'150', DEFAULT);

-- object: public.days | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.days CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.days(
        id smallint NOT NULL,
        name varchar,
        CONSTRAINT days_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
ALTER TABLE public.days OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO public.days (id, name) VALUES (E'1', E'sunday');
INSERT INTO public.days (id, name) VALUES (E'2', E'saturday');
INSERT INTO public.days (id, name) VALUES (E'3', E'friday');
INSERT INTO public.days (id, name) VALUES (E'4', E'monday-thursday');

-- object: public.periods | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.periods CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.periods(
        id smallint NOT NULL,
        description varchar,
        name varchar,
        CONSTRAINT periods_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
ALTER TABLE public.periods OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO public.periods (id, description, name) VALUES (E'1', E'Summer holidays', E'super peak');
INSERT INTO public.periods (id, description, name) VALUES (E'2', E'Easter & Christmas, Feb., May & Oct. Half Term', E'peak');
INSERT INTO public.periods (id, description, name) VALUES (E'3', E'Non-holiday', E'off-peak');

-- object: public.prices | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.prices CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE public.prices(
        id smallint NOT NULL,
        amount money,
        restrictions varchar,
        id_hires smallint NOT NULL,
        id_rooms smallint NOT NULL,
        id_days smallint NOT NULL,
        id_periods smallint NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT prices_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
ALTER TABLE public.prices OWNER TO postgres;

-- object: hires_fk | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE public.prices DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS hires_fk CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE public.prices ADD CONSTRAINT hires_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_hires)
REFERENCES public.hires (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- object: rooms_fk | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE public.prices DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS rooms_fk CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE public.prices ADD CONSTRAINT rooms_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_rooms)
REFERENCES public.rooms (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- object: days_fk | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE public.prices DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS days_fk CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE public.prices ADD CONSTRAINT days_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_days)
REFERENCES public.days (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- object: periods_fk | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE public.prices DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS periods_fk CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE public.prices ADD CONSTRAINT periods_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_periods)
REFERENCES public.periods (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: above code how to break the "whole venue" to 4 rooms item table reference that value to rooms table?  because existing system use that kind of structure
------------------
venue table
----------------
1.Infinity
2. Eternity
3.Meridian Ballroom
4.Grand Ballroom

Comment: i need to store 4 ids from venue table to one row price table that will be count as "Whole venue "... how to design table for it

Comment: You don't.  One can rent both ballrooms (ie the whole venue), or just one of them.  Apart from that, you can rent both suites or one of them.  No relation between ballrooms and suites, you don't put them in one table.

Comment: i need to store 4 ids from venue table to one row price table that will be count as "Whole venue "... how to design table for it

Comment: The table has been designed.  It's called "prices".  You may need to learn about a relational database, if you want to work with MySQL.

Comment: cant we design  pivot  table between room and price to hold the rooms count? instead of giving "whole room" for 4 rooms

Comment: there is a link between the ballroom and suits, (two suits combination possible according to client discussion) all 4 suits + ballrooms called "Whole Venue"

Comment: can we put addhr_price, corkage_price in price table? instead rooms

Comment: No we can't, because they're only related to the room, not to eg. days or periods.

Comment: ok, tkx for your comment